# not getting expected output from command prompt (Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, command-prompt

In my Qt program I'm trying to run the following command prompt command.

```
QProcess process;
   process.start("cd", QStringList() << "C:\\PROGRA~1\\CCleaner");
   QString output;
   process.waitForFinished(-1);
   output = process.readAllStandardOutput();
   output= process.readAllStandardError();
```

I figured this out over the course of looking at a bunch of other questions on here but for me I'm not getting the expected output from either of the read functions which is an error that you get when you try to "cd" into a directory that doesn't exist. Command prompt gives the error "the system cannot find the specified path" (nothing is being assigned to the variable by either of the functions)

Why isn't my output variable being assigned that message as a QString? I thought I might've had to add process.execute() but then when I realized that the function requires a parameter I figured it was unnecessary not to mention none of the other related questions I mentioned it was needed.

Any know where I went wrong? By the logic of every question I found this code should've worked hence why I'm stumped.

Comment: `cd` is not an executable you can run. It's just a built-in command that `cmd.exe` command processor understands natively. You can run `cmd /c cd somedir` if you are so inclined.

Comment: [QDir::cd()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#cd) might better suit your needs.

Comment: @O'Neil Your suggestion worked as well but for the sake of how much I've already written imma go with Igor's since it's a quick fix and doesn't require adding a library to the header. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik thanks that worked I had assumed from the answers to the other questions that I read that the start function required more than one argument but I also wouldn't have known that the string had to be written that way.

Comment: If you just want to check if a path exist, then there is `QDir::exists()` or `QFileInfo::exists()`